# How to get distinct values when searching for y in the equation x+y=t?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am working on the 2 sum problem, where I search for t-x (or y) to find if x + y = t and if there is a value added to x that makes the sum be in t.

T is all values from `-10000` to `10000` inclusive. I implemented an `nlogn` solution because I did not know how to use a hash table (and most examples I see are for characters not integers). My `nlogn` solution is to use quick sort to sort the numbers, then use binary search to search for `t-x`.

I believe my problem is that currently I am also entering duplicates. An example, in the array {1,2,3,4,5} if t was 5, 2+3 and 1 + 4 equals five, but it should only give one, not two. In other words, I need to get all "distinct" or different sums in t. I believe that is what is wrong with my code. Supposedly the line x!=y should make it distinct, although I do not understand how and even when implemented still gives me the wrong answer.

Here is the link for the data file with test cases: 
http://bit.ly/1JcLojP
The answer for 100 is 42, 1000 is 486, 10000 is 496, and 1000000 is 519. My output is 84,961,1009, and I did not test 1 million.

For my code, you can assume binary search and quick sort are properly implemented. Quick sort was supposed to give you how many times it compared things, however i never figured out how to return two things (the comparisons and the index).

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

long long binary_search(long long array[],long long first,long long last, long long search_key)
{
    long long index;    
    if (first > last)
        index = -1;
    else
    {
        long long mid = (first + last)/2;
        if (search_key == array[mid])
            index = mid;
        else
            if (search_key < array[mid])
                index = binary_search(array,first, mid-1, search_key);
            else
                index = binary_search(array, mid+1, last, search_key);
    } // end if
    return index;
}// end binarySearch

long long partition(long long arr[],long long l, long long h)
{
    long long i;
    long long p;
    long long firsthigh;
    p = h;
    firsthigh = l;
    long long temporary = 0;

    for (i=(l +0); i<= h; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[p])
        {
        long long temp2 = 0;
        temp2 = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[firsthigh];
        arr[firsthigh] = temp2;
        firsthigh ++;
    }
}
temporary = arr[p];
arr[p] = arr[firsthigh];
arr[firsthigh] = temporary;
    return(firsthigh);
}

long long quicksort(long long arr[], long long l, long long h)
{
    long long p;                  /* index of partition */
        if ((h-l)>0)
        {
            p = partition(arr,l,h);
            quicksort(arr,l,p-1);
            quicksort(arr,p+1,h);
        }
        if(h == l)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        long long array[1000000] = {0};
    long long t;
    long long count = 0;
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("/Users/SeanYeh/downloads/100.txt");
    cout<<"part 1"<<endl;
    for (long long i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        inData >> array[i];
        //cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }inData.close();
    cout<<"part 2"<<endl;
    quicksort(array,0,100);
    cout<<"part 3"<<endl;
    for(t = 10000;t >= -10000;t--)
    {
    for(int x = 0;x<100;x++)
    {
        long long exists = binary_search(array,0,100,t-array[x]);
        if (exists >= 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
cout<<"The value of count is: "<<count<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The code is C++, not C.

Comment: My bad, I did not know there was a C++ tag. I will change it.

Comment: @user1470901 To return two things in `C++` either return a `struct` or modify one of the actual variables passed to the method and return the other one.

Comment: You might get some useful insights from the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110647/maps-and-vectors-stl-in-c).

Comment: Your assumption that `quicksort` is correct isn't correct, because `partition` is broken.

Comment: @M.Shaw Thanks I will try that and hopefully it will work! :)

Comment: @molbdnilo How so? I ran my quick sort and it sorted the array just fine. In addition, with the new code given by  xashru my program runs fine. I understand that it is weirder than normal because it does not use extra memory and it either always uses the first or last element as the pivot (I had to program multiple variations on quick sort) but how is partition broken?

Comment: @user1470901 `h` is "one past" the content. If you pass it an array with `h` elements you will access the array out of bounds. (Which is why [this](http://ideone.com/wMZZkI) gets a runtime error.) At the moment you're just accessing a zero that's lying around past your data, which is why it seems "just fine".

Comment: @molbdnilo so all i have to do is change it to: quicksort(arr,p+1,h-1); and p = partition(arr,l,h-1);? Because if I do so, it gives me are horribly assorted array (as in the array is unsorted). And when I enter it in there, it says time limit exceeded which might be better than throwing an error. How can I show my results?

Comment: @user1470901 The quicksort function itself looks correct. In `partition`, I *think* you only need to change to `p = h - 1;`, and use `i < h` for the loop boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates you need to change your binary search range from `[0,n]` to `[x+1,n]`. Also once you find that a sum exists break out of the loop.

```
long long exists=binary_search(array, x+1, 100, t-array[x]);
if(exists >= 0)
{
    count++;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to return duplicate values *don't keep searching from the beginning of the list*.

Example:

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5}
total = 5
```

- Start your loop at the first item (1)
- Now do your binary search on the rest of the items (`{2,3,4,5}`)

  - Doing this will return the value 4
- Second time around, the loop starts at 2

  - Binary search is done on `{3,4,5}`
- etc

A problem arises in the case that you have duplicate items, so the list

```
{1,1,2,3,4,5} or {1,1,1,2,3,4,5}
```

This will yield 2 results even with the method I've shown, if this is acceptable to you ignore the next part of this answer, otherwise you can eliminate this by using **[std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)**.

When you get the list, you put it in a set. The set will automatically eliminate duplicates for you and then you can continue with the method I've shown above.

**Note:** std::set is implemented internally as a binary search tree, so you can also get rid of your quicksort and binary search implementations because `std::set` does both